# I would like to know if there a way to display specific data of current log in android studio and user using mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am  building an app in which a client log in and see their transaction base on their customer code ,I would like to know if it's possible to retrieve data from a table just for the user that logged in and display it? and i would like to know how to do it.

Transaction.php

```
include 'DatabaseConfig.php';

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);

if ($conn->connect_error) {

 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT transaction_num, customer_code FROM tbl_order_of_payment";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {


 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $tem = $row;

 $json = json_encode($tem);


 }

} else {
 echo "No Results Found.";
}
 echo $json;
$conn->close();
?>

DatabaseConfig.php
<?php

//Define your host here.
$HostName = "localhost";

//Define your database username here.
$HostUser = "root";

//Define your database password here.
$HostPass = "";

//Define your database name here.
$DatabaseName = "customer_portal_epayment";

?>
```

connection.php

```
$host = "localhost";
$user_name = "root";
$user_password= "";
$db_name = "customer_portal_user";


$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user_name,$user_password,$db_name);


?>
```

Login.php

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password_hash = $_POST['password_hash'];


require_once 'connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username'";

$response = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$result = array();
$result['login'] = array();

if ( mysqli_num_rows($response) === 1){

  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response);

  if( password_verify($password_hash, $row['password_hash'] )){

    $index['username'] = $row['username'];
    $index['email'] = $row['email'];
    $index['cust_code'] = $row['cust_code'];

    array_push($result['login'], $index);

    $result['success'] = "1";
    $result['message'] = "success";
    echo json_encode($result);

    mysqli_close($conn);
  } else {

    $result['success'] = "0";
    $result['message'] = "error";
    echo json_encode($result);
    mysqli_close($conn);
  }
<?php
```

HttpServicesClass.java

```
    public int responseCode;

    public String message;

    public String response;

    public ArrayList<NameValuePair> ArrayListParams;

    public ArrayList <NameValuePair> headers;

    public String UrlHolder;

    public String getResponse()
    {
        return response;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }

    public int getResponseCode()
    {
        return responseCode;
    }

    public HttpServicesClass(String url)
    {
        HttpServicesClass.this.UrlHolder = url;

        ArrayListParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        headers = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    }

    public void AddParam(String name, String value)
    {
        ArrayListParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    public void AddHeader(String name, String value)
    {
        headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    public void ExecuteGetRequest() throws Exception
    {
        String MixParams = "";

        if(!ArrayListParams.isEmpty())
        {
            MixParams += "?";

            for(NameValuePair p : ArrayListParams)
            {
                String paramString = p.getName() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(),"UTF-8");

                if(MixParams.length() > 2)
                {
                    MixParams  +=  "&" + paramString;
                }
                else
                {
                    MixParams += paramString;
                }
            }
        }

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(UrlHolder + MixParams);

        for(NameValuePair h : headers)
        {
            httpGet.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
        }

        executeRequest(httpGet, UrlHolder);
    }

    public void ExecutePostRequest() throws Exception
    {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(UrlHolder);
        for(NameValuePair h : headers)
        {
            httpPost.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
        }

        if(!ArrayListParams.isEmpty())
        {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(ArrayListParams, HTTP.UTF_8));
        }

        executeRequest(httpPost, UrlHolder);
    }

    private void executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request, String url)
    {
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);

        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 10000);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

        HttpResponse httpResponse;
        try
        {
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
            responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            if (entity != null)
            {
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

                response = convertStreamToString(inputStream);

                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is)
    {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try
        {
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                is.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

SessionManager.java

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public Context context;
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    private static final String PREF_NAME = "LOGIN";
    private static final String LOGIN = "IS_LOGIN";
    public static final String EMAIL = "EMAIL";
    public static final String CUST_CODE = "CUST_CODE";
    public static final String USERNAME = "USERNAME";

    public SessionManager(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    }

    public void createSession(String email, String username, String cust_code){
        editor.putBoolean(LOGIN, true);
        editor.putString(EMAIL, email);
        editor.putString(USERNAME, username);
        editor.putString(CUST_CODE, cust_code);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public boolean isLoggin(){
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(LOGIN, false);
    }

    public void checklogin(){

        if (!this.isLoggin()){
            Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            ((HomeActivity)context).finish();
        }
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetail(){
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
        user.put(EMAIL, sharedPreferences.getString(EMAIL, null));
        user.put(USERNAME, sharedPreferences.getString(USERNAME, null));
        user.put(CUST_CODE, sharedPreferences.getString(CUST_CODE, null));

        return user;
    }

    public void logout(){

        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(i);
        ((HomeActivity) context).finish();
    }
}
```

Transaction.java

```
    ListView MobileDetailsListView;
    ProgressBar MobileProgressBar;
    SessionManager sessionManager;
    String HttpUrl = "http://192.168.2.231/android_register_login/TransactionData.php";
    List<String> MobileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> MobileArrayAdapter ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_epayment);

        sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
        sessionManager.checklogin();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logocopy);
        MobileDetailsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        MobileDetailsListView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
        MobileProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        new Epayment.GetHttpResponse(Epayment.this).execute();

        MobileDetailsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShowDetailsActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("ListViewValue", MobileList.get(position).toString());

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });


    }

    private class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        public Context context;

        String JSonResult;

        public GetHttpResponse(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {
            HttpServicesClass httpServicesClass = new HttpServicesClass(HttpUrl);
            try
            {
                httpServicesClass.ExecutePostRequest();

                if(httpServicesClass.getResponseCode() == 200)
                {
                    JSonResult = httpServicesClass.getResponse();

                    if(JSonResult != null)
                    {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                        try {
                            jsonArray = new JSONArray(JSonResult);

                            JSONObject jsonObject;

                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                            {
                                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                MobileList.add(jsonObject.getString("transaction_num").toString());



                            }
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, httpServicesClass.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

        {
            MobileProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            MobileDetailsListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Start code for remove duplicate listview values.

            HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();

            hashSet.addAll(MobileList);
            MobileList.clear();
            MobileList.addAll(hashSet);

            //End code here for remove duplicate values.

            MobileArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Transaction.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, MobileList);

            MobileDetailsListView.setAdapter(MobileArrayAdapter);


        }
        HashMap<String, String> user = sessionManager.getUserDetail();
        String mUsername = user.get(sessionManager.USERNAME);
        String mEmail = user.get(sessionManager.EMAIL);
        String mCust_code = user.get(sessionManager.CUST_CODE);

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            this.finish();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }


}
```

Login.java

```
   private EditText username, password_hash;
   private Button btn_login;
   private TextView link_regist;
   private ProgressBar loading;
   //this is the JSON Data URL
   //make sure you are using the correct ip else it will not work
   private static  String URL_LOGIN = "http://192.168.2.231/android_register_login/login.php";
   SessionManager sessionManager;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

       sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);

       loading = findViewById(R.id.loading);
       username = findViewById(R.id.username);
       password_hash = findViewById(R.id.password_hash);
       btn_login = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);




       btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

               String mUsername = username.getText().toString().trim();
               String mPass = password_hash.getText().toString().trim();

               if (!mUsername.isEmpty() || !mPass.isEmpty()) {
                   Login(mUsername, mPass);
               } else {
                   username.setError("Please insert username");
                   password_hash.setError("Please insert Password");
               }
           }
       });

   }

   private void Login(final String username, final String password_hush) {

       loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       btn_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);

       StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
               new Response.Listener<String>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(String response) {
                       try {
                           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                           String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                           JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");

                           if (success.equals("1")){

                               for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                                   JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                   String username = object.getString("username").trim();
                                   String email = object.getString("email").trim();
                                   String cust_code = object.getString("cust_code").trim();

                                   sessionManager.createSession(username,email,cust_code);

                                   Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                   intent.putExtra("username", username);
                                   intent.putExtra("email", email);
                                   intent.putExtra("cust_code", cust_code);
                                   startActivity(intent);

                                   loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                               }

                           }
                       } catch (JSONException e) {

                           loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                           btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                           Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Username and Password don`t match" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                   }
               },
               new Response.ErrorListener() {
                   @Override

                       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                       loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Email and Password don`t match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   }
               })
       {
           @Override
           protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
               Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
               params.put("username", username);
               params.put("password_hash", password_hush);
               return params;
           }
       };

       RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
       requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Transaction.php

Just Change this line:

```
$id  = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT transaction_num, customer_code FROM tbl_order_of_payment WHERE id=$id";
```

here your `$id` is you need to pass it into API/Webservice,where id is also unique this will get when you have login service, from there you can get and pass it in this service for transaction fetch

Comment: This recommends to make the application vulnerable to sql injection attacks. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2412335) for further details.